# From two input text field when i enter data on one, if something is entered on the next one it must vanish.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From two input text field when i enter data on one, if something is entered on the next one it must vanish and value must be stored were choice is entered..

suppose i created two inputs for like and not like depending upon users opinion along with the reason.
user must be able to enter only and only one field.
if he enter the other field the value from first field must delete.
kindly help guys i am too new to javascript and jquery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Regarding your problem, [what have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also, may I suggest that your requirement isn't very friendly to the user: if they go to the trouble of entering something in one of the fields and then accidentally type in the other they'll lose their work. It would be nicer to prompt them somehow to give them a chance to cancel the delete.

Comment: try adding some codes

Comment: Please provide your htmnl code. Are you using input text boxes or radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <input type="text" id="like" value="">

 <input type="text" id="dislike" value="">

<script>
$('input').on('keyup',function() {
    $(this).siblings().val('');
})
</script>
```